# Passing entire object by id after authenticating user

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, express-jwt

I have created a login system using JWT and also created profile route where a user can see his/her data which I have passed in JWT during login.

Now I want to list entire object of loggedin user by `_id`. How can I do this?

Right now I can only fetch details which I am passing in JWT login route:-

```
router.get('/adminProfile', checkAuth, (req, res, data) =>{ 

    if(req.userData.role2 === 'admin') {
        Admin.find().then(users => res.json(req.userData))
        .catch(error => res.json({error}))
    } else {
        res.status(401).send(["Not authorized. Only  admin can check details."]);
    }
});
```

**In login:-**

```
     if (result && admin.admins.verified === "true"){
                        const adminEmaill = admin.admins.email;
                        //console.log(adminEmaill);
                        const role2 = admin.admins.email===adminEmaill? "admin" : "user";
                        const token = jwt.sign( 
                            {
                                userId: admin._id,
                                address: admin.address,                         
                                email: admin.admins.email,
                                role2   
                            },
                            process.env.JWT_KEY,
                            {
                                expiresIn : "1h"
                            });
```

So I am getting `userId` , `address` , `email` in response. But there is more data in the object which I am passing through registration. I want entire object to be called of this specific user by `id`. *How can I modify my profile route ??*

Comment: i supposed `Admin.find()` is the some kind of ORM (fetch from DB). What's the point of you querying from DB if you are returning `req.userData`?

Comment: @anasceym yes i know , that's what I am asking I want to pass only single value in JWT for authorization and want to fetch object from DB after verification. But not getting how will I query ?

Comment: So now you already got the `id` from the JWT token, you need to check documentation of the library you are using to query Admin table from DB using that `id`.

Comment: @anasceym tried this but getting res 401 err msg `Admin.findOne({ _id: req.body.id }, function(err, doc) {
    if (err) throw err
      if (doc) {
    res.json(doc);
   console.log(doc);
    } else {
        res.status(401).send(["Not authorized. Only  admin can check details."]);
    }`

Comment: Now you try this, to replace `req.body.id` with `req.userData.userId ` in the DB query. let me know if that helps

Comment: @anasceym yes this helps . Thank You. So the info I am getting , can be used to do further operations and will the same data will get change to db ?